# Number of positive solutions to $\log_{10}(x+\pi)=\log_{10}x+\log_{10}\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

For $x>0$, how many solutions does this equation have?
$$\log_{10}(x+\pi)=\log_{10}x+\log_{10}\pi$$
I just don't know where to start. I'm not very familiar to log functions and log problems in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the right-hand side using the property $\log ab=\log a+\log b$:
$$\log_{10}(\pi+x)=\log_{10}\pi x$$
Exponentiate both sides by 10:
$$\pi+x=\pi x$$
This is a linear equation in $x$ and therefore has only one solution.
$$x=\frac\pi{\pi-1}$$

Comment: You guys make this problem seem 10 times easier than how I think...

Answer (score 1):

Try to exponentiate using the laws of logarithm resp. exponential,
$$
x+π=x\cdot π
$$
has an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(x+\pi)=\log(x)+\log(\pi)=\log(x\pi)$$

$$x+\pi=x\pi$$

$$x=\frac\pi{\pi-1}$$